# Chrome Debugger - Not breaking into scripts (however opening index instead)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Im hoping this is a simple thing I am just missing - however I have gotten used to using the Chrome Developer tools when debugging Javascript. However, for some reason it has started to miss-behave a little bit.

So, I have a Javascript method with a `debugger;` on the first line within the method:

```
function importTasks() {
debugger;
    var serviceURL = appRoot + 'Register/ImportTasks'

    $j.ajax({
        type: "post",
        etc...
    });
}
```

which exists between a `<script></script>` tag on a cshtml view.
When I hit the method, DevTools breaks and goes here:

[image]

Now I have broken into Javascript code in this very same file in very much the same way a little while ago with no problems - which makes me think, have I unknowingly changed a property somewhere??

I have not seen this before and am hoping some one can easily advise what I might have done to cause this to happen?

Comment: Are you debugging transpiled code? Bundled and minimised code? More input of the current code you are trying to debug would be helpful for the rest of the users to offer you help.

Comment: The Javascript is just a function that exists between some <script> tags on the View... Not anything different to what I have debugged in the past with no problems as far as I can see...?

Comment: Dude, we need more to go off of than one single screenshot of the debugger paused. Give us some code, and some examples of where the script is erroring out at least...

Comment: Of course... I quickly typed the question up on the go so will try and get a bit more detail in there shortly...! Cheers!

Comment: Hope that helps some??

Comment: Not sure if the screenshot is working properly??

Answer (score 0):

I had Visual Studio open in the background but was not running the application - just idle. I closed this down and it has been working fine since. I guess DevTools and VS are battling behind the scenes for debugging - even though VS is not actually running any debugging!? Strange!